# Entity Framework Class with Extra Field

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity

im working with Entity Framework, SQL and C#.

I have a table on SQL called Clients.

I have to show the clients on a Grid in a Form and select some of the clients using a Check. So, i need 1 check for each client on the grid. I try with "Anonymous Types" but this are ReadOnly properties and i need ReadWrite properties. It is possible? what i have to do?.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a grid on your application's user interface. It sounds like the data source for this grid would have been a list of Clients. It also sounds like the grid needs a checkbox for you to select each Client as you like. It also sounds like you want to bind an anonymous type to the grid, but you haven't mentioned why you chose that as the solution.

- What is your UI being built with - ASP.NET webforms, WinForms, WPF?
- What is the checkbox supposed to represent? Is it meant to store data, or is it meant to indicate that some work needs to be done on each selected Client?
- What action needs to happen when the checkbox is selected?